# Will Time Machine backup an iTunes library that's stored on an external HD?

Tags: itunes, time-machine, external-disk, time-capsule

As part of a family 'computer shuffle/switcheroo' I'm thinking of repurposing a Mac Mini as a media-server running iTunes (to feed our library of video content to our Apple TVs). However, I will need to store the iTunes *library* on an external hard drive since the Mac Mini has only a 500GB internal drive and the iTunes library currently exceeds 1TB.

Obviously I would want the iTunes library backed up; all our family computers are backed up to a single 3TB Time Capsule. My concern is whether or not the external drive with the iTunes library would get backed up; AFAIK external drives do not get backed up via Time Machine (am I correct about that?), but I wondered if the the linkage between the iTunes app (residing on the Mac Mini) and its library (on the external) would maybe provide a bridge that would allow the iTunes library to be included in the backup.

Can anyone advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Time Machine will backup external drives as well. Just make sure that the drive is not excluded in the settings:

System Preferences > Time Machine > Options…

Comment: Ah, so I was wrong in my initial supposition that external drives don't get backed up? Okay, thanks.

Comment: Please check the "options…" button in the preferences pane to be sure. :)